# Magento getting this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeText() on a non-object

Tags: php, magento

I am getting the error above in a new template I created in order to show the manufacturer's image. I am using this in the view.phtml file and it works just fine. But since this is custom, I figured there would be problems. Hopefully I can figure this one out.

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
    $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
    $category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
    $currentCategoryId = $category->getId();
    $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($currentCategoryId);
    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $brand = $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
?>
<div class="landing-page nested-container">
    <?php foreach ($children as $category): ?>
    <div class="vertical-section grid12-4 mobile-grid-half">
        <a href="<?php echo $category->getRequestPath(); ?>">
            <img class="center-block" alt="<?php echo $category->getName(); ?>" src="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()."media/catalog/category/".Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->getThumbnail(); ?>" />
            <div class="caption category-boxes-logo full-width">
                <?php echo '<img src="'.$this->getBaseUrl().'media/wysiwyg/infortis/brands/'.str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($brand)).'.jpg" alt="'.$brand.'"></a>' ?>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: `var_dump($product);`

Comment: Where do I place that?

Comment: $product is not an object because $this don't have it. Try to inspect what $this is.

Comment: I tried to do a var_dump and I still get a NULL Fatal Error

Comment: Try `die(get_class($this))` instead, that will give just the class name of the block which is important to know.  Or you could just tell us what type of block you created.

Comment: It's a core/template block - I placed the template block in template/catalog/category

Answer (score 0):

You may only call `getProduct()` for a block which supports it.  That generally means a descendant of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` although there are others.  When creating a block you can specify any type that meets your needs.

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" template="path/to/your/template.phtml" />
```

These blocks get their product object from the registry, which is only set for product pages by the catalog controller.  If you have to use another block type which does not have a `getProduct()` function then you can access the registry directly.

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
```

---

It seems to me that you need the `manufacturer` from products in a given category, and there are several categories to inspect.  I assume any product from a category will do.  This does not require the block to be a `catalog/product_view` type.

```
<?php
    $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
    $category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
    $children = $category->getChildrenCategories();
?>
<div class="landing-page nested-container">
    <?php foreach ($children as $category): ?>
    <!-- Load a product brand per category -->
    <?php $product = $category->getProductCollection()->getFirstItem() ?>
    <?php $brand = $product ? $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') : 'default' ?>
    <div class="vertical-section grid12-4 mobile-grid-half">
        <a href="<?php echo $category->getRequestPath(); ?>">
            <img class="center-block" alt="<?php echo $category->getName(); ?>" src="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()."media/catalog/category/".$category->getId()->getThumbnail(); ?>" />
            <div class="caption category-boxes-logo full-width">
                <?php echo '<img src="'.$this->getBaseUrl().'media/wysiwyg/infortis/brands/'.str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($brand)).'.jpg" alt="'.$brand.'"></a>' ?>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I am now getting this error when I tried that:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getMetaTitle() on a non-object in /html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php on line 56

Comment: I am using a CMS block to generate the template. This is what the coding looks like right now doing so: {{block type="catalog/product_view" template="catalog/category/list.phtml"}}

Comment: Your CMS syntax looks correct.  The error above would happen if there is no "current_product" registered, that suggests the page you are looking at is not a product detail page.

Comment: No, it's not. I'm sorry for not clarifying that. This is a custom block that I am using on a Landing Page for a Category. I can send you the link so you can see where I am trying to get it to work.

Comment: Which product did you expect to get?  Is there another way of getting the brand/manufacturer?  If necessary it is possible to create an attribute for categories instead of products.

Comment: I'll explain what I am looking for... If you go here: http://www.williamsjewelers.net/designers.html You will see all active subcategories showing specifically for Designers. When you hover over each subcategory on that page, you see the default manufacturer logo. This is done manually right now. I am looking to get this working automatically so I don't have to keep editing that page when a link or an image changes. I already have the code working to show all subcategories just fine. The issue I have now is getting the proper hover image to work for each subcategory. If this makes sense.

Comment: I also have this working just fine on the Product Detail page like you mentioned before. I now just need to get it working on each Landing Page and I will be good to go.

Comment: It's possible the 'working just fine' product detail page is loading the wrong brand for each category.  Please check it and see if my edit helps.

Comment: No no, the product detail page has no issues. I know I'm loading the proper brands.

Comment: The issue is on the page link I sent. The landing page for each main category.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I can do. I just used the product name as they should be matching anyway and used the same string I was trying to use for the Manufacturer. I am posting my answer for anyone who may want an answer down the road:

```
<?php
    $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
    $category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
    $currentCategoryId = $category->getId();
    $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($currentCategoryId);
?>
<div class="landing-page nested-container">
    <?php foreach ($children as $category): ?>
        <div class="vertical-section grid12-4 mobile-grid-half">
            <a href="<?php echo $category->getRequestPath(); ?>">
                <img class="center-block" alt="<?php echo $category->getName(); ?>" src="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()."media/catalog/category/".Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->getThumbnail(); ?>" />
                <div class="caption category-boxes-logo full-width">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl().'media/wysiwyg/infortis/brands/'.str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower($category->getName())).'.png' ?>" alt="<?php echo $category->getName(); ?>">
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

I also just used a normal block type of core/template instead of what was suggested in a previous answer. This worked like a charm for me.